# Were there some changes to Electron 5 and 6 that would prevent inbound IPC connections?

Tags: javascript, node.js, electron, ipc, node-ipc

I had a working setup of communication between Electron and a regular Node application via [Node-IPC](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-ipc) in Electron 4.1.5. After no changes except upgrading to Electron 6, I can only send IPC communications out from Electron. Electron cannot receive responses via Node-IPC. Receiving messages fails silently.

I scoured the documents, release notes, blog posts, issues threads, Stack, and the Electron Slack channel for any leads, but I've found *absolutely nothing*.

I'm making my IPC connection from the `main` process, not a `renderer`, so the `chromium-sandbox` theoretically shouldn't be a factor, if it's even enabled by default which I'm not sure that it is.

My question is, what changes in Electron 6 have potential to affect a previously working inter-process communication setup?